# Reading a file does not re-initiate using PHP

Tags: php, moodle, filereader

I have this code to initiate db connection based on the logged in user credential, the issue with it is that it works on the first page (landing page). If I navigate from the landing page it does not initiate the connection again. I'm wondering what could be wrong?
If I manually add the user's credentials to it, it works perfectly, but when it's dynamically added, it fails to re-initiate again if I navigate from the landing page. 
When I read the PHP log in MAMP it always displays this error. Anyway to make it re-initiate if I navigate from the landing page?

Error

```
[31-Aug-2018 21:51:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  fopen(send.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/moodle35/config.php on line 7
[31-Aug-2018 21:51:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/moodle35/config.php on line 8
[31-Aug-2018 21:51:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$libdir in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/moodle35/lib/ajax/service.php on line 33
[31-Aug-2018 21:51:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  require_once(/externallib.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/moodle35/lib/ajax/service.php on line 33
[31-Aug-2018 21:51:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/externallib.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.15/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/moodle35/lib/ajax/service.php on line 33
```

The code
     // require_once('send.txt');
        require_once('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/register/DBConnect.php');

```
    $myFile = "send.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $myFileContents = fread($fh, 21);
    //fclose($fh);
    $mytrimmedvalue = trim($myFileContents);

    unset($CFG);
    global $CFG;
    $CFG = new stdClass();

if ( $mytrimmedvalue != '' ) {

    $database = new dbConnect();
    $db = $database->openConnection();

    $sql = "select * from ol_users where username = '$mytrimmedvalue'";
    $user = $db->query($sql);
    $result = $user->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    debug_to_console($result[0]['serverhosturl'] .'---------' .$mytrimmedvalue .'----------' .$result[0]['databasename']);
    $CFG->dbtype    = 'mysqli';
    $CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
    $CFG->dbhost    = $result[0]['serverhosturl'];
    $CFG->dbname    = $result[0]['databasename'];
    $CFG->dbuser    = $result[0]['serveruser'];
    $CFG->dbpass    = '111111ade';
    $CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
    $CFG->dboptions = array (
      'dbpersist' => 0,
      'dbport' => '',
      'dbsocket' => '1',
      'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    );

    $CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost:8888/moodle35';
    // $CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://192.168.0.199:8888/moodle35';
    $CFG->dataroot  = $result[0]['moodledataurl'];
    $CFG->admin     = 'admin';

    $CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/setup.php');
    //$database->closeConnection();
 }

function debug_to_console( $data ) {
    $output = $data;
    if ( is_array( $output ) )
        $output = implode( ',', $output);
        echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );</script>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$myFile = dirname(__FILE__) . "/send.txt";
```

When the file path is used in other places rather than your root it cannot be found, because `fopen` cannot locate the file with relative path in current dir. Use absolute path

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give it a shot. Appreciate a bunch.